# Pulse train profile generator for stepper drive step/dir input

Tags: clock, pulse, stepper-driver

All, I am trying to create a circuit to control a stepper drive step/dir input.  I'd like to generate pulses starting at 1kHz and ramp up to a 10kHz peak, then decelerate to 1kHz until motion is stopped.  I.e., a ramp up/down pulse profile.  I know there are great motion control units on the market to accomplish this, but I am running my application on a Rasperry Pi 3 B+ and interfacing to those products is tedious (and more expensive).  It seems that adding a secondary RC circuit to a 555 astable circuit might accomplish this.  Anyone have a solution?  Thx!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. We do not provide schematics nor out of the box solutions: however, if you have an idea or if you are experimenting with a circuit, we'll surely help you if you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a microcontroller with better fine delay control such as something from the TI MSP430 series. They can generate the pulses directly.

With an RPi, if you only need rough control, try a LM566. It is a voltage controlled oscillator with a 10X range. That is, the frequency can be varied 10x without changing the RC values. That would seem to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response - that is exactly what I was looking for!